# How to get the exit status of a Make target script command to return as the Make command exit status itself?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, exitstatus

I have a Make target which runs a shell script that return an exit status 45 (lets say).

After running the Make target as command on shell , I want to check the $? variable value giving me 45 or not. But it is giving me '2'.

For example, below is my Makefile.test:

```
mytarget:
    test.sh
```

And test.sh content is as below:

```
#!/bin/sh
exit 45
```

After running make -f Makefile.test mytarget, I am running echo $? which is giving me 2. 
How can I get the same exit status as test.sh after running the Make command on prompt?

Thanks

Comment: You can't.  The exit codes for `make` are documented in the manual (and in the POSIX spec for make) and those are the codes that you'll get.  It's important to remember that `make` is NOT a scripting language.  You don't get to have control over its command line or its exit code, like you would for a language like shell or Python or Perl or whatever.

Comment: It bears repeating: `make` is NOT a scripting language.  If you want to write a script then use the (a) shell language directly. Or use Python, Ruby, Perl, Tcl, or whatever other scripting language works for you.